# Can I pass a file into the browser then manipulate it with javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser

I understand that javascript running in the browser would not be allowed to access a local file system directly, it make sense and I am not looking for a way to violate that.

However are there any safe and kosher ways to grab files from the local system for the browser to use? Would these methods be platform specific? Would I be limited it what kinds of files and would access have to be granted on a per file basis?

What I am thinking about is when you upload photos, it will open a system level dialog and then eventually present that file to the browser for the browser to send to a remote server via http.  Would it then be possible to pass a file in to the browers local memory/ give the browser permission to read it as it were to be upload but instead of uploading it somehow pass over to java script and allow it to manipulate it client side much in the way you can manipulate files with server side javascript?

The reason I am asking is because I have recently become interested in browser-based file manipulation programs, their feasibility and what could be done with them in a Chrome OS type environment. Just out of curiosity then any idea of it being practical any time soon.

edit: attempted to clarify and make my question more direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) (MDN has [a tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications)) but be aware that it is a new specification and has [limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=file+api).

It allows files selected in an `<input type="file">` to be accessed with client side JS.